# ViewBinding still generate import "android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;"

Tags: android, gradle, android-viewbinding

I'm working on a relatively recent Android project (last updated 2020, was migrated to AndroidX).

When I was building the project, got this error, which was related to viewbinding:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

[image]

First time I encountered such error, and AFAIK `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` is deprecated. No idea why viewbinding generate that line.

This is the content of build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 119
        versionName "1.0.76"
        buildConfigField "long", "TIMESTAMP", System.currentTimeMillis() + "L"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true

        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
//            useProguard false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules-debug.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled false

        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "tier"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            versionCode 6000
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            dimension "tier"
        }

        local {
            versionCode 6000
            versionNameSuffix "-local"
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            dimension "tier"
        }

        prod {
            dimension "tier"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
    lint {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/dspread_android_sdk_2.6.7.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.6'
    implementation 'org.thoughtcrime.ssl.pinning:AndroidPinning:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.39.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.yalantis:ucrop:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:astickyheader:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:2.0.4'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
    implementation 'com.github.dbachelder:CreditCardEntry:1.4.9'
    implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'

    implementation 'com.pixplicity.easyprefs:EasyPrefs:1.10.0'

    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

To the best of my knowledge, it doesn't contain any Android support/legacy stuffs. I tried "Invalidate caches", wiping the `.gradle` directory, cleaning and rebuilding the project a few times... didn't work.

How to solve this

Comment: That would indicate that your `activity_pay.xml` layout has an `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>` element in it. View binding isn't really generating that; it's just reading what's in your layout files.

Comment: Ah yes you're right. I just checked the `activity_pay.xml`, and indeed it used the old `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`. Replaced that with `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>` and it worked fine.